# Jena Virtuoso Load Model

Tags: rdf, jena, virtuoso

I read different tutorials explaining how to load a Model to a Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint using Java Apache Jena (e.g. https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/), but I am not able to make it.

I tried this function:

```
public void uploader(){ 
String myVirtuosoEndpoint = "http://10.1.22.17:8890/"; //my Virtuoso endpoint IP

Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() ; //the Model I want to upload
model.createResource("https://example.org").addProperty(RDF.type, "http://myType");
try (RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(myVirtuosoEndpoint)) {
                conn.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
                conn.load("http://myGraph", model);
                conn.commit();
                conn.end();
        }
}
```

I also tried this other function, leveraging Jena's Txn library (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/txn/txn.html).

```
try (RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(myVirtuosoEndpoint)) {
        Txn.executeWrite(conn, ()-> {
             conn.load(targetGraph, model);
        }) ;
}
```

I am using a OpenLink Virtuoso Server version 07.20.3217. As for the Jena dependencies I am using the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/jena-rdfconnection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-rdfconnection</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It seems that code works as I don't get any error, but the graph where I want to upload the model does not change. I am verifying it by simply executing a SPARQL query against the Graph after executing the code.

Anyone with the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget `conn.end()` maybe` And did you try `Txn.executeWrite(conn, ()->conn.load("http://myGraph", model));`? How do you evaluate that the graph is empty or not changed? Is writing to your Virtuoso via HTTP enabled, i.e. the permissions?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Virtuoso-specific documentation for Jena](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider)? What version of Virtuoso, and is it Open Source or Enterprise? And what versions of Virtuoso Jena Provider, Virtuoso JDBC Driver, Java? Any of these may be a relevant detail...

Comment: You don't need the `conn.write`.  `conn.load` on its own should work.

Comment: "http:///10.1.22.17:8890/" has 3 slashes at the start.

Comment: @AndyS Thanks for the letting me know about the typo. Anyway, the function does not work yet. Not even without the conn.write()...

Comment: @AKSW I tried both with the conn.end() and also with the Txn library, but it still does not work. I evaluate if the execution of these functions work or not, simply by making a SPARQL query in the SPARQL endpoint. Regarding the permissions, I am not sure about them. Where can I find them and manage them? In the Conductor or in a separate file?

Comment: You don't need the TXn either.  When remote, an operation is a transaction if and only if the other end does it as a transaction.  The client can't influence Virtuoso through these standards APIs.  I suggest looking in the Virtuoso logs to see if the operation arrived at all and whether it completed successfully, and then dump the database so as to see the changes.

Comment: @AndyS it seems the problem is the operation does not arrive, since the virtuoso.log file does not change when the function is executed... Anyway, the is executed without errors, so I don't really know what is going on...

Comment: Is the URL right? It usually has "/sparql"

Comment: If I add the /sparql in the end of the SPARQL endpoint, I get the following error when executing `conn.load(..)`. `org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException: 400 - Bad Request`

Comment: @AndyS I found a solution to the problem. I think it is a different approach, but at least it works well. This solution was based on the solution provided in this [link](https://github.com/iesnaola/EEPSA_ETL/tree/master/eepsa.etl.load)

Comment: `com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model` -- That's quite old now. The package names have changed to bne under `org.apache.jena`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying another new approach to update the content of an RDF graph in Virtuoso.

Code:

```
//Connect to Virtuoso
VirtModel virtualModel = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(GRAPH_NAME, endpoint, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
long modelInitialSize = virtualModel.size();

//Add model
virtualModel.add(model);
long modelNewSize = virtualModel.size();

virtualModel.close();
```

Where the endpoint is similar to `jdbc:virtuoso://10.1.22.xxx:1111`

I am using these dependencies in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/jena-tdb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/apache-jena-libs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Furthermore, I am using the *virt_jena3.jar* and *virtjdbc4.jar* dependencies from [Virtuoso webapge](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload)

Now I am getting the following error when trying to get the VirtModel's size with the command `long modelNewSize = virtualModel.size();`:

`org.apache.jena.shared.JenaException: virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoException: Problem during serialization : Software caused connection abort: socket write error`.

Besides, once this error appears, it seems like the Virtuoso server goes down, and I need to restart the Virtual Machine to fix it.

The tricky part is is that with dependencies available [here](https://github.com/iesnaola/EEPSA_ETL/blob/master/eepsa.etl.load/pom.xml), the same code works perfectly...